# Chef update node fromGit

Tags: git, jenkins, chef-infra

How do I update the application code in chef node with updated code from a git repository through Jenkins.
I need to update the application whenever there is a commit to the master.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you would do this by connecting in over SSH and running `sudo chef-client`, either via Jenkins or a tool like RunDeck. You can also set up Chef to run in interval mode where it automatically converges every N minutes (usually 30 but you could turn that down).

Comment: Hi just wanted to add that this client-server is a windows server

Comment: Then you would use WinRM or set things up as a scheduled task.